# incorrect display lineWidth=1 at html5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have example: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/4_5_canvas_linewidth.html
But first line is not equals 1 pixel:
[image]
How can i fix this? (browser Google Chrome)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Always add 0.5 pixel to the position of your line to prevent the anti-aliasing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors#A_lineWidth_example

Comment: Thanks! I must begin path from x = 0.5 not 1.0

Comment: I was struggling with it for hours until I came across this answer. That's weird but it solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

To make life easier you can move the whole canvas by 0.5px:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5); // Move the canvas by 0.5px to fix blurring
```

It prevents anti-aliasing on all graphics, except images, so you'll have to use +0.5px only for images.

Comment: -1 This removes the anti-aliasing for odd widths, but adds anti-aliasing for even widths.

Comment: Works for lines but not for ‍‍`ctx.fill()`